# Application Error : express and socket.io with node.js in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, socket.io, cloud9-ide

my source is here.. it's simple code...

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);


http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
```

Sorry, My English is very bad.
I  wish you would understand.

I want express and socket with same port.

how can I ?

I'm using cloud 9 and

not error on this IDE's debug mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `createServer` twice. Just 1 `createServer` and 1 `listen`.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);


server.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
```